# How to use binary matrix in CSV for apriori alogorithm in r

Tags: r, apriori

I am trying to use the binary matrix containing transactions for the apriori algorithm I don't know how to implement it

```
data_purchase
   Txn Bag Blush Nail.Polish Brushes Concealer Eyebrowpencil Bronzer
1    1   0     1           1       1         1             0       1
2    2   0     0           1       0         1             0       1
3    3   0     1           0       0         1             1       1
4    4   0     0           1       1         1             0       1
5    5   0     1           0       0         1             0       1
6    6   0     0           0       0         1             0       0
7    7   0     1           1       1         1             0       1
8    8   0     0           1       1         0             0       1
9    9   0     0           0       0         1             0       0
10  10   1     1           1       1         0             0       0
11  11   0     0           1       0         0             0       1
12  12   0     0           1       1         1             0       1
```

The above is the data frame containing the binary matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the R package `arules` at https://cran.r-project.org/package=arules